# Dependent dynamic dropdown using JSP, Servlet, JQuery and denormalized Mysql table

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jsp, servlets

Please have a look at the sample denormalized DB shown below:

```
|----|---------------|---------|------------------------|---------------|----------------------|
| id | continent     | country | state                  | city          | street               |
|----|---------------|---------|------------------------|---------------|----------------------|
| 1  | North America | USA     | California             | San Francisco | Broadway             |
| 2  | South America | Brazil  | Sao Paulo              | Campinas      | R. Dr. Emilio Ribas  |
| 3  | South America | Brazil  | Sao Paulo              | Campinas      | R. Dr. Vieira Bueno  |
| 4  | Asia          | India   | Maharashtra            | Mumbai        | C.S.                 |
| 5  | Asia          | India   | Maharashtra            | Mumbai        | S.V.                 |
| 7  | Europe        | Germany | North Rhine-Westphalia | Duisburg      | Essenberger          |
| 8  | Europe        | Germany | North Rhine-Westphalia | Bochum        | Solingen             |
| 9  | Europe        | France  | Lorraine               | Toul          | Dijon                |
| 10 | Europe        | France  | Lorraine               | Verdun        | 50 Avenue            |
| 11 | North America | USA     | Massachusetts          | Boston        | Saint Alphonsus      |
| 12 | North America | Canada  | Ontario                | Kingston      | 1st Avenue           |
| 13 | North America | Canada  | Ontario                | Kingston      | 7th Avenue           |
| 14 | North America | Canada  | British Columbia       | Kamloops      | Albert               |
| 15 | North America | USA     | Massachusetts          | Boston        | Eliot                |
|----|---------------|---------|------------------------|---------------|----------------------|
```

The value of each dropdown list comes from database shown above. street's value depends upon value of city, city's value depends on value of state, state's value depends on value of country and country's value depends on value of Continent.

For Example: if I select North America as a Continent, then dropdown for Country should show only USA and Canada. Next if I select USA, then dropdown for State should show only California and Massachusetts and so on. Can anyone please help me to achieve the solution when database is denormalized using jquery/JSP/Servlet?

As of now, I have done following coding. I have used jquery and written a jsp:

```html
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Dependent Dropdown</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#continent').change(function() { fillOptions('country', this); });
                $('#country').change(function() { fillOptions('state', this); });
                $('#state').change(function() { fillOptions('city', this); });
                $('#city').change(function() { fillOptions('street', this); });
            });
            function fillOptions(childID, parentID) {
                var child = $('#' + childID);
                $.getJSON('json/options?child=' + childID + '&val=' + $(parentID).val(), function(opts) {
                    $('>option', child).remove(); // Clean old options first.
                    if (opts) {
                        $.each(opts, function(key, value) {
                            child.append($('<option/>').val(key).text(value));
                        });
                    } else {
                        child.append($('<option/>').text("Please select parent"));
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select id="continent" name="continent">
                <c:forEach items="${continent}" var="option">
                    <option value="${option.key}" ${param.continent == option.key ? 'selected' : ''}>${option.value}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <select id="country" name="country">
                <option>Please select parent</option>
            </select>
            <select id="state" name="state">
                <option>Please select parent</option>
            </select>
            <select id="city" name="city">
                <option>Please select parent</option>
            </select>
            <select id="street" name="street">
                <option>Please select parent</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `Servlet` behind `/json/options` looks like:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.amey.dao.AddressDAO;
import com.amey.dao.AddressDAOImplementation;

@WebServlet("/CascadingDropdownController")
public class CascadingDropdownController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( CascadingDropdownController.class.getName() );
    private AddressDAO dao;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CascadingDropdownController() {
            dao = new AddressDAOImplementation();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.info("In doGet ");
        String child = request.getParameter("child"); // ID of child DD to fill options for.
        String val = request.getParameter("val"); // Value of parent DD to find associated child DD options for.
        Map<String, String> options = null;
        try {
            options = dao.find(child, val);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String json = new Gson().toJson(options);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
}
```

Honestly, I am not clear about the DAO imoplementation. I need help with the DAO logic.

Answer (score 0):

distinct list of continents:

```
 SELECT t.continent
   FROM mysqltable t
  GROUP
     BY t.continent
```

---

distinct list of country for a given continent:

```
 SELECT t.country
   FROM mysqltable t
  WHERE t.continent = 'North America'
  GROUP
     BY t.continent
      , t.country
```

---

distinct list of state for a given continent and country:

```
 SELECT t.state
   FROM mysqltable t
  WHERE t.continent = 'North America'
    AND t.country   = 'Canada'
  GROUP
     BY t.continent
      , t.country
      , t.state
```